# Create custom wordpress url to query data from external database

Tags: wordpress

so, I have a Wordpress Setup with a custom homepage template. In the template I query some products from an external database. Now I want to create a detail of a product, and this is where im stuck..

I don't know how to implement this since there is no data in the WP db thus no actual url (I guess?).. I thought about making 1 page in WP called 'Detail' and make the href attribute on the homepage products like this 'www.example.com/detail/123', get the id from the url en with that id query to the database..

Is this the right approach? Hope someone can help..

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, you want to query content from one wordpress website to another right ?

The right way to do it is to use JSON APIs which will let u retrieve the content you need using HTTP requests.

You can set these APIs yourself, refer to the [following](https://webdevstudios.com/2014/10/16/an-overview-of-wordpress-json-api/) tutorial.

Thus, you can also use this wonderful wordpress plugin : 
[JSON API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/)

After installing and enabling the plugin you'll have to set your API links according to the content you need to get, for example the following api:

```
http://example.com/api/get_posts/?post_type=custom_post_type&count=3
```

queries the latest 3 custom posts along with their fields and custom fields (if present).

Find more examples [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/).

Now on your other website where you want to display the content you 'll need to use [JSON decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert the JSON string into a PHP obect or array.
For example:

```
$json = '{"a":hello,"b":hi,"c":hey,"d":yo,"e":ola}';
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data->{'a'}
// this should echo the value "hello"
```

As stated [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170519/displaying-content-with-wp-rest-api#answer-170522).

I hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think he wants to query another WordPress. He only says that he fetches data from another database that contains products.

Your idea is pretty close to what you have to do. Take a look at [add_rewrite_rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule), [add_rewrite_tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag) and [get_query_var](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var).

This tuts is a good example for you: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/custom-page-template-page-based-on-url-rewrite--wp-30564